# Minikube bootstrapping fails

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When I run `minikube --start` on my Mac (Mojave) it fails when it tries to run `kubeadm init`.

Here's the full command I ran:

```
minikube start --logtostderr --stderrthreshold 0 -v 9 
               --cpus 2 --memory 4096 --disk-size=50g 
               --vm-driver=hyperkit
```

And here are the errors I got:

```
I0118 09:48:09.580726    4563 utils.go:224] ! error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
I0118 09:48:09.580831    4563 utils.go:224] !   [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.15:47850->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout
I0118 09:48:09.580857    4563 utils.go:224] ! , error: exit status 1
I0118 09:48:09.580938    4563 utils.go:224] !   [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.13.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.15:36115->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout
I0118 09:48:09.580967    4563 utils.go:224] ! , error: exit status 1
I0118 09:48:09.581030    4563 utils.go:224] !   [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.13.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.15:52487->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout
I0118 09:48:09.581048    4563 utils.go:224] ! , error: exit status 1
I0118 09:48:09.581110    4563 utils.go:224] !   [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.13.2: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.15:33294->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout
I0118 09:48:09.581128    4563 utils.go:224] ! , error: exit status 1
I0118 09:48:09.581175    4563 utils.go:224] !   [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.15:44064->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout
I0118 09:48:09.581191    4563 utils.go:224] ! , error: exit status 1
I0118 09:48:09.581236    4563 utils.go:224] !   [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.2.24: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.15:57861->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout
I0118 09:48:09.581258    4563 utils.go:224] ! , error: exit status 1
I0118 09:48:09.581546    4563 utils.go:224] !   [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.6: output: Error response from daemon: Get https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io on 192.168.64.1:53: read udp 192.168.64.15:37549->192.168.64.1:53: i/o timeout
```

When I run `minikube logs` I see the following message:

`server.go:261] failed to run Kubelet: unable to load bootstrap kubeconfig: stat /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf: no such file or directory`

If I run `minikube ssh` and list the contents of `/etc/kubernetes` this is what I see:

```
> cd /etc/kubernetes   
> ls
addons  manifests
```

I get the same error for minikube versions 0.32.0 and 0.33.0.

Comment: That error implies there's a problem connecting to the Google Container Registry hosting the image. Are you behind a corporate firewall of some sort? This could happen because of firewalls in company networks. Have you tried setting a specific Kubernetes version like specified here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#specifying-the-kubernetes-version
`minikube start --kubernetes-version v1.13.1`

Comment: I'm getting this error off the company network. If I run `kubeadm config images pull` manually on the minikube machine I get "could not fetch a Kubernetes version from the internet". If I try to curl any URL from the minikube machine it fails to resolve the address so I guess it's some kind of DNS issue?

Comment: I get the same issue with kubernetes version 1.13.1 too. I do have McAfee Endpoint Security installed and the status for that says a firewall is enabled. Is there a way to check if that's interfering with minikube?

Comment: try this two topics [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111631/cannot-download-docker-images-behind-a-proxy/28093517#28093517) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728355/kubernetes-pods-not-starting-running-bind-the-proxy/43757872#43757872)

Comment: Thanks @aurelius but I'm not actually behind a proxy so that's not the issue. The issue seems to be that the minikube vm can't resolve the url to an ip address. docker pull works fine on the host without any need to set any proxies.

Comment: can you disable McAfee and try again? Or maybe with different network? We can clearly see that the issue is with downloading the images, especially when you specified that `kubeadm config images pull` does not work.