# How do I kubectl using a proxy server?

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster running using private endpoint (using steps mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/enabling-dns-resolution-for-amazon-eks-cluster-endpoints/)). I can `kubectl` from the worker.

I have an inbound (in Route 53) to my worker and I am able to resolve `dig @<inbound_ip> <cluster_endpoint>.xyz.region.eks.amazonaws.com` from my laptop.

I wanted to know if there is a way to make `kubectl` use a proxy so that it resolves to the inbound_ip. I tried using export `HTTPS_PROXY=https://inbound_ip:443` but that did not work (I want to do this without setting up the dns forwarder).

I looked at this [kubectl behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482485/kubectl-behind-a-proxy) but that is more about minikube and couldn't find anything else related to this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually started an HTTP(S) proxy on the node?

Comment: No, I have not. The AWS guide doesn't say that, it only talks about setting up an inbound endpoint to worker so I assumed the worker would already have the capability to forward those requests? Could you please share how to do that if you don't agree with my comment?