# "Unable to connect to the server: Forbidden" on kubectl and helm commands only when running with Ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl

I want to automate `kubectl` and `helm` commands using Ansible. The target machine is configured properly, so that both works on the cli in a manual shell (e.g. `kubectl get nodes` or `helm list`). But when trying to make any API calls like get the server version

```
- name: List charts
  shell: kubectl version -v=8
```

It breaks with a *Forbidden* error. The verbose logging doesn't give me much more details:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd: kubectl version -v=10
  delta: '0:00:00.072452'
  end: '2020-02-27 15:22:36.227928'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 255
  start: '2020-02-27 15:22:36.155476'
  stderr: |-
    I0227 15:22:36.224517   27321 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/user/.kube/config
    I0227 15:22:36.225211   27321 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.11.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/a452946" 'https://k8smaster01:6443/version?timeout=32s'
    I0227 15:22:36.225975   27321 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://k8smaster01:6443/version?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
    I0227 15:22:36.225986   27321 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
    I0227 15:22:36.226062   27321 helpers.go:219] Connection error: Get https://k8smaster01:6443/version?timeout=32s: Forbidden
    F0227 15:22:36.226080   27321 helpers.go:119] Unable to connect to the server: Forbidden
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: 'Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.3", GitCommit:"a4529464e4629c21224b3d52edfe0ea91b072862", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-09T18:02:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}'
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

However, when sending a manual request to those API url like this

```
- name: Test master connection
  shell: curl -k https://k8smaster01:6443/version?timeout=32s
```

It works:

```
stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: |-
    {
      "major": "1",
      "minor": "11",
      "gitVersion": "v1.11.3",
      "gitCommit": "a4529464e4629c21224b3d52edfe0ea91b072862",
      "gitTreeState": "clean",
      "buildDate": "2018-09-09T17:53:03Z",
      "goVersion": "go1.10.3",
      "compiler": "gc",
      "platform": "linux/amd64"
    }
```

#### Why API calls with `kubectl` doesn't work when executed with Ansible?

I'm behind a proxy server, but `k8smaster01` is set in `no_proxy`. Ansible got it, I printed `$no_proxy` in the task for testing purpose.

For `curl` I used `-k` since its a self signed cert from k8s. This sould harm `kubectl` (which itself works when not running from Ansible). It also doesn't work when calling `kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true get node` with Ansible.

Comment: Did you try to force set KUBECONFIG environment variable in ansible to the kubernetes config path that you use when login through shell?

Comment: kubectl works fine with ansible as through using shell or command module as k8s module. (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html). I have several playbooks using it.

Comment: @matiferrigno I tried `kubectl version --kubeconfig=/home/user/.kube/config -v=8` (which should be equivalent to setting `KUBECONFIG` env variable), but with the same result. I found out that the behavior of Ansibles execution is the same as when I run `kubectl` with `sudo`. However, Ansible runs with `user` without `become` (which would result in `sudo`) - `whoami` gave me `user. Seems strange to me

Comment: @matiferrigno I already tried the build-in modules. The problem is that I want to install multiple third party helm charts, packed as `tgz` archives, but the `helm` module from Ansible doesn't seem to support archives (just folders or git repos).

Comment: It is true, I had a lot of troubles with the helm module and I had to work around that.

Maybe this could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482485/kubectl-behind-a-proxy

Comment: Some times is NO_PROXY (uppercase) in other systems is no_proxy (lowercase).

Comment: Are there any contraindications in your case to run **Ansible** on the same host, on which you run `kubectl` commands and use [k8s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html) and [helm](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/helm_module.html) modules rather than **shell** ? I thing it could make it more straightforward. Have you possibility to test it not from behind the proxy ? Setting `$no_proxy` env variable may not always work and have the desired effect.

Comment: @matiferrigno I reset all *_proxy env variables for the task to empty strings, since I need the proxy just for internet connections, not for the internal k8s servers. Now I get `Connection error: Get https://k8smaster01:6443/api?timeout=32s: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup None on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving`. I replaced `127.0.0.53` by our internal dns server (that could resolve k8smaster01) for testing purpose in `/etc/resolv.conf` and got the same error but with the IP of our DNS instead of `127.0.0.53`. Its a proprietars MS DNS from AD.

Comment: @mario For testing purpose I run Ansible on my local PC where `kubectl` is configured. The `helm` module doesn't seem an option since I need to install helm charts by packed archive, but according to the docs of the underlying python module (the Ansible module itself doesn't cover this) it doesn't support this currently.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to unset the env variables from the proxy (since the proxy is required just for internet access) by setting empty environment variables:

```
- name: Kubectl test
  become: false
  shell: kubectl get no -v=10
  environment:
    http_proxy:
    https_proxy:
    no_proxy:
    HTTP_PROXY:
    HTTPS_PROXY:
    NO_PROXY:
```

This was a bad idea, since `curl` (which seems to be used inside `kubectl`) parse this to `None` and fail. Strangely, `kubectl` failed with an dns error:

```
skipped caching discovery info due to Get https://k8smaster01:6443/api?timeout=32s: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup None on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
```

Found out that the main problem was that I set `NO_PROXY=$no_proxy` in `/etc/environment`, where `no_proxy` contains the hostname `k8smaster01`. Since `/etc/environment` doesn't resolve bash variables, the uppercase `NO_PROXY` just contains `$no_proxy` as string. So it was enough to replace `NO_PROXY=$no_proxy` by the corresponding value (e.h. `NO_PROXY=k8smaster01`).

It wasn't an issue before, because most applications seems to follow the Linux specification of using lowercase environment variables for proxy usage.

Comment: Hi @lion I thinking and... did you try add localhost networks on $no_proxy env var? localhost,127.0.0.1... or already have you it?

Answer (score 1):

On a local cluster (server listening on `https://0.0.0.0:<any port>`), put 0.0.0.0/8 in NO_PROXY, else kubectl (verify with kubectl cluster-info) will try to use your configured proxy.